# Moving objects in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a game in Python (tkinter), but I've never written in Python before.
The objects I'm trying to move are ovals called "mines"

```
def create_mines():
  x1 = randint(600,800)
  y1 = randint(600,800)
  x2 = randint(600,800)
  y2 = randint(600,800)
  r = randint(5,100)
  mine = c.create_oval(x1,y1, x2, y2)
  bubble_r.append(r)
  bubble_id.append(mine)
```

the list name is bubble_id, and each mine is stored in the list. I'm trying to move the ovals up to the top of the canvas, and my instructions are to move them using a for loop. Do I use the for loop to traverse the list? And how do I ensure the mines keep moving up throughout the program's runtime? Also, the base code I've been given doesn't take any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You use `for` loop to create more mines and to traverse list with mines.

You have to use `root.after` to run repeatedly function which moves mines with a small step. This way you don't stop mainloop.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

# --- functions ---

def create_mines(canvas):

    bubbles = []

    for __ in range(10):

        x = random.randint(0, 400)
        y = random.randint(0, 400)
        r = random.randint(5, 10)

        mine = canvas.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r)

        bubbles.append( [mine, r] )

    return bubbles


def moves_mines(canvas, bubbles):

    for mine, r in bubbles:

        #canvas.move(mine, 0, -1)

        # get position
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(mine)

        # change 
        y1 -= 1
        y2 -= 1

        # if top then move to the bottom
        if y2 <= 0:
            y1 = 300
            y2 = y1 + 2*r

        # set position
        canvas.coords(mine, x1, y1, x2, y2)

    # run after 40ms - it gives 25FPS
    root.after(40, moves_mines, canvas, bubbles)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

bubbles = create_mines(canvas)

# run after 40ms - it gives 25FPS
root.after(40, moves_mines, canvas, bubbles)

root.mainloop()
```